# How do I remove a DOM element or empty it from a component

Tags: angular

I have a dom element, generated automatically by an external component.

```
<div id="abc">test data</div>
```

I would like to remove, hide or empty the content, whichever is easier.

Comment: use *ngIf directive.
Add a property in component for example `visible`.
And set it to `false` in `ngOnInit`.
In template use `<div id="abc" *ngIf="visible">test data</div>`

Comment: Can you change the example HTML to show something closer to your actual code? As written, it's hard to tell how this external component is inserted and how you might be able to manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is quite odd, because before `ngOnInit()` nothing is rendered yet. So I guess you want it to be hidden on loading of the component? You can use `*ngIf`:

```
<div *ngIf="showTestData" id="abc">test data</div>

@Component({})
export class TestComponent {
  showTestData: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // nothing necessary here
  }
}
```

Comment: The DOM element is automatically generated by an external component I use. I don't have control on that external component.

Comment: That sounds like weird behaviour. Is the DOM element inserted inside your component?

Comment: The HTML element is in the DOM, when the page loads.

Comment: but how will you know when it's inserted? Because on ngOnInit the component is not rendered yet

Comment: can i delete it in ngAfterViewInit() or inside ngAfterContentInit()?

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="abc"><span *ngIf="show_it">test data</span></div>`
And you declare `show_it` as a member variable of the component class, and set it to false in ngOnInit.

Of course, you can put the `ngIf` on the `div` directly.

*Edit after your comments*
If you know the id for sure and it comes from outside, you can use `@ViewChild` to select the element and hide it once you get a hold of it.